# Declared type string is not compatible with assigned type string[] error

Tags: arrays, string, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using the code below:

```
//@version=5

indicator("Currency Strength Indicator", shorttitle="CSI", overlay=false)

// Define the currency pairs to compare

var string currencyPairs = input("EURUSD,GBPUSD,AUDUSD,USDJPY", "Currency Pairs")

// Split the currency pairs into an array

var string[] pairs = str.split(currencyPairs, ",")

// Initialize an array to store the currency strengths
var float[] strengths = array.new_float(0)

// Calculate the currency strength for each pair

for i = 0 to array.size(pairs) - 1

    var string pair = pairs[i]
    var float pairClose = request.security(pair, "D", close)
    var float currencyStrength = pairClose / pairClose[1]
    array.push(strengths, currencyStrength)

// Calculate the average currency strength

var float averageStrength = array.avg(strengths)

// Plot the currency strength line

plot(averageStrength, "Currency Strength", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
```

However I keep getting this error:

> Declared type string is not compatible with assigned type string[]

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the array with the wrong syntax. You need to do it like this, not with the square brackets

```
for i = 0 to array.size(pairs) - 1
    var string pair = pairs.get(i)
```

You will run into another error with the request security function though. The security needs to be constant and known at runtime, it can't change with the loop.

You'll need to declare each pair as a constant and then use multiple requests.

```
pair1 = 'EURUSD'
pair2 = 'GBPUSD'
pair1Close = request.security(pair1, 'D', close)
pair2Close = request.security(pair2, 'D', close)
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply.
Can you pls giveme an example of what you mean when you say that I will need to declare each pair as a constant and then use multiple requests.?

Comment: added an example to my answer